# AsyncLayoutInflater, gridLayout and rotating

Tags: android, layout-inflater

For performance reasons I had to implement layout inflating with help of new [AsyncLayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AsyncLayoutInflater.html). Everything works great and smoother but problem comes when fragment is recreated after pressing back button (or rotating device etc.). The gridlayout is suddenly invisible or rather non-dimensional. Piece of code for better understanding:

```
AsyncLayoutInflater inflater = new AsyncLayoutInflater(getActivity());
do {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxx, gridLayout, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
        public void onInflateFinished(View view, int resid, ViewGroup parent) {
            //some logic
            parent.addView(view);
            Log.d(TAG, parent.getChildCount() + " " + parent.getWidth() + "x" + parent.getHeight());
        }
    });
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

The log line describes the problem. When first coming to fragment the grid is populated and stretched to screen's match_parent. But when rotating or going to next screen and coming back the grid is only populated and not stretched.
Logs looking like this:

First: 1 1920x750, 2 1920x750, 3 1920x750, 4 1920x750 ...

Rotating: 1 0x0, 2 0x0, 3 0x0, 4 0x0 ...

P.S.: Original equivalent code with synchronous LayoutInflater works without problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You have a cursor, so why are you not using a CursorAdapter? Why do you need the AsyncLayoutInflater?

Comment: It's just how the database is designed. The code is old and of big company and  I cannot edit everything. However I can adjust this part of code and try to optimize it. Let's focus on the AsyncLayoutInflater problem, not how code/database etc may be bad desgined/used.

Comment: I'm not understanding how a database design prevents you from implementing a CursorAdapter

Comment: Problem is that each of those views may be different and are very heavy. That is why it is better to inflate them asynchronously.